# Sitecore Publishing application is missing in the start menu

Tags: sitecore

I'm a beginner to sitecore. I created my first basic web site. When I tried to publish my site, the publish item is missing from the start menu. I'm using the sitecore xpress edition. I use the admin login to do my sample web site. Please help me to publish my sample web site I created.

Answer (score 3):

There's no publish feature in the xpress edition of Sitecore. It uses "live publishing", meaning your changes will be published as soon as you save them.

[This page](http://sitecorejohn.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!960125F1D4A59952!119.entry?sa=346812794) has a bit more info on the Xpress edition of Sitecore.